# Web Calendar Sync using .ics export

Tags: google-calendar, export, calendar, apple-ical

I have a web based calendar that has an .ics export so my users can import my calendar into theirs, whatever type of calendar they may have. To do so the user must click on a button on the web app and save the .ics file to their local environment.

The export is manual and now I'm looking to somehow automate the process so the user can receive calendar updates without even logging into my web app.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to automate this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to publish the ics as an iCal feed that they can paste as a URL to import an external calendar

Tripit, for example:

webcal://www.tripit.com/feed/ical/private/*private-hash*/tripit.ics

So you need to come up with some kind of hash and publish the ics at a particular url for the user. It is not completely secure as far as I can tell, but that way they won't have to log into the app - their calendar will automatically load the external calendar

The only downside is they do need to add the external calendar on each of their calendars. For example, I have to import tripit on both my Google Calendar *and* my iPhone